# Problema al generar formulario a través de consulta con ajax en PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un campo de búsqueda para obtener los registros en tiempo real, pero, dentro del resultado que quiero obtener se debería crear un formulario y dentro del formulario los inputs correspondientes, pero lo que me genera es solamente etiquetas form para abrir y para cerrar, los inputs aparecen después...

Éste es el código con Ajax:

```
<script>
function obtener_registros(buscar){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax/buy/resultado.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data : { producto: buscar }
        }).done(function(resultado){
           $("#resultado").html(resultado);
     })
 }

$(document).on('keyup focus', '#busqueda', function(){
    var valorBusqueda = $(this).val();
    if (valorBusqueda != "") {
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }else {
        obtener_registros();
    }
});
```

Y este es el código PHP:

```
<?php

$matPrim = MateriaPrimaData::getAll(); //Función que utilizo para obtener todos los registros

if(isset($_POST['producto'])){
    $matPrim = MateriaPrimaData::getLike($_POST['producto']); //Cuando se escribe algo dentro del cuadro de búsqueda
}
?>

<?php if (count($matPrim)>0): ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <th>C&oacute;digo</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Descripci&oacute;n</th>
            <th>En Inventario</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>Precio Unitario</th>
            <th style="width:100px;"></th>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($matPrim as $mp): ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:80px;"><?php echo $mp->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mp->nombre; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mp->descripcion; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mp->existencias; ?></td>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="cantidadMP" placeholder="Cantidad" min="1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="precioMP" placeholder="Precio Unitario" min="0.01">
                </td>
                <td style="width:100px;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idMP" value="<?php echo $mp->id; ?>">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Agregar</button>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php   else: ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        No hay productos disponibles.
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

El problema es que dentro del form no aparecen los inputs, lo que aparece es lo siguiente:

```
<form method="post" action=""></form>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, y de antemano, Gracias!

Comment: "dentro del resultado que quiero obtener se debería crear un formulario y dentro del formulario los inputs" cada vez que buscas resultados "en tiempo real" quieres que se genere eso?? puedes explicar un poco mejor?

Comment: Es que en el código del resultado se crea un formulario, y dentro de él hay etiquetas td y hay inputs, pero cuando obtengo el resultado el formulario se crea a parte, sin ningún elemento td ni input dentro de él...

Comment: Toda esa tabla que creas la obtienes en el ajax?

Comment: Sí, la tabla sí la genera... El problema es con el formulario, lo genera pero sin elementos dentro de él

Comment: Intentas crear uno **¡o más!** formularios dentro de un bucle `foreach`... ¿Crees que es una buena idea? Si hubiese 100 elementos dentro del bucle estarías creando 100 formularios. Imagino que quieres tener **un solo formulario**, no que se cree uno en cada iteracción del bucle. Y además, si te fijas bien, estás metiendo el formulario dentro de una fila (`<tr>`)  de una tabla.

Comment: Haz una prueba: quita los `<td>` de dentro del `<form>`. Lo de crear el `<form>` dentro de una tabla sencillamente no está permitido (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table), de un `<tr>` solo pueden colgar `<td>` o `<th>`(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634715/which-dom-elements-can-be-child-of-tr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente, el problema era que estaba introduciendo etiquetas `<td>` dentro del formulario, lo cuál no es correcto y por eso tenía el error.